# Why does the Scala worksheet evaluate the stream?

Tags: scala

I am new to Scala. I created two streams, which I am assuming are lazily evaluated. The first one appropriately has a '?'. However, I was expecting the second one to also correctly construct. Why does the Scala interpreter evaluated the stream.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are invoking [`Stream.apply`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.3/scala/collection/immutable/Stream$.html#apply[A](xs:A*):scala.collection.immutable.Stream[A]) on the companion object `Stream`.

The `apply` method has signature:

```
def apply(as: A*): Stream[A]
```

In particular, there are no arguments that are passed by-name with `=>`. Thus, every argument passed to `apply` is evaluated immediately. Here, `(1/0)` is evaluated immediately, and throws an exception.

---

If you want to evaluate the second element lazily, you can use `fill`:

```
val s = 42 #:: Stream.fill(1){ 1/0 }  // works
s.take(2).toList                      // throws exception
```

Comment: Barely beat me! Well played.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo by 5 seconds, yeah... That's like code-golfing regex questions here^^ xD

Answer (score 0):

The `Stream.apply` function (which you're calling when you do `Stream(...)`) doesn't take its arguments by name.

From [scala.collection.immutable.Stream](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.3/scala/collection/immutable/Stream$.html#apply[A](xs:A*):scala.collection.immutable.Stream[A]).

> ```
> def apply[A](xs: A*): Stream[A]
> ```

So it takes all of its arguments the "usual" way. Your `1/0` is being evaluated before it's ever put into the stream.